# crawl and copy another sites content

Tags: php, web, copy

I want to crawl and copy another site content (just text) and  find specific content  download links between specific tags . how can I do this? i am using Cpanel and Php

Comment: Your question not clear. Please edit it into short, simple sentences.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not sure about your question, but I think you want to do [scrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping).
Using PHP, you can use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) for instance. That will load an URL and, with [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) you will be able to parse HTML and find content, links etc you want.